# R: Converting cartesian to polar and sorting

Tags: r

Consider a polygon (with out hole) with the vertices in cartesian co-ordinate system:

```
> X=
             x           y
[1,] -10.951654  5.1999753
[2,]  -8.648792  7.5526423
[3,]  -5.682459  8.2535191
[4,]  -1.714430  6.4598705
[5,]  -1.606767  3.1157852
[6,]  -0.143845  0.3147358
[7,]   3.823051 -1.4814188
[8,]   7.789705 -3.2781072
[9,]  10.053431 -0.8261339
[10,]  13.061571 -0.2348249
[11,]  13.394428 -3.4885483
[12,]  11.767807 -7.5279214
[13,]   9.264051 -9.3765475
[14,]   5.298010 -7.5785077
[15,]   1.331421 -5.7816749
[16,]  -2.635669 -3.9859493
[17,]  -6.603322 -2.1914693
[18,] -10.571699 -0.3985887
[19,] -14.541248  1.3916934
[20,] -14.102558  4.9583269
[21,] -10.951654  5.1999753
```

Here is the plot of the polygon with centre (red point)[image]
Transforming **X** into polar co-ordinate system

```
 >theta_1=(atan(X[,2]/X[,1]))
 >r_1=sqrt((X[,1]^2)+(X[,2]^2))
```

Assume the centre as (0,0). Now I want to arrange the points as increasing values of theta taking values from **0** to **2*pi**.

Stuck here in doing this.

Any suggestion!!

Comment: Does the **Added later** means that you want to arrange data with increasing `theta_1` and decreasing `r_1`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `atan` returns values from `-pi/2` to `pi/2`, you can convert the theta value calculated to *(0, 2*pi)* conditioning on the sign of `(x, y)` coordinate. Something like this may work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
coords <- as.data.frame(X)
mutate(coords, theta = ifelse(x < 0, atan(y / x) + pi, 
                             ifelse(y < 0 , atan(y / x) + 2*pi, atan(y / x)))) %>% 
arrange(theta)
            x          y    theta
1   -1.714430  6.4598705 1.830213
2   -0.143845  0.3147358 1.999484
3   -1.606767  3.1157852 2.046914
4   -5.682459  8.2535191 2.173755
5   -8.648792  7.5526423 2.423749
6  -10.951654  5.1999753 2.698298
7  -10.951654  5.1999753 2.698298
8  -14.102558  4.9583269 2.803502
9  -14.541248  1.3916934 3.046177
10 -10.571699 -0.3985887 3.179278
11  -6.603322 -2.1914693 3.462029
12  -2.635669 -3.9859493 4.128153
13   1.331421 -5.7816749 4.938726
14   5.298010 -7.5785077 5.322500
15   9.264051 -9.3765475 5.491752
16  11.767807 -7.5279214 5.714082
17   7.789705 -3.2781072 5.884856
18   3.823051 -1.4814188 5.913504
19  13.394428 -3.4885483 6.028398
20  10.053431 -0.8261339 6.201195
21  13.061571 -0.2348249 6.265209
```

If the points are in the second or third quadrants, add `pi` to the `atan()`; if the points are in the fourth quadrant, add `2*pi` to the `atan()`; else keep itself. In this way, you guarantee that your theta lies in `(0, 2*pi)`.

Comment: Thanks. I got the main points. Could you please further explain what is "coords" the above code. If I take coords=X, then it is showing the following error: is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE

Comment: `coords` is the data.frame version of `X`. Just updated the answer.

Comment: It is working fine. There was a problem in my code. I fixed it.